# euclidian distance with repeated IDs

Tags: python

I have this data frame and I am trying to calculate the euclidian distance for each point using x,y,z coordinates:

```
ID   X     Y     Z
1  10.0  10.0  10.0
1  12.0  12.0  12.0
1  14.0  14.0  14.0
1   8.0   8.0   8.0
1   8.1   8.1   8.1
1   8.2   8.2   8.2
2  10.1  10.1  10.1
2  16.0  16.0  16.0
2  18.0  18.0  18.0
2  21.0  21.0  21.0
2  21.1  21.1  21.1
2  21.2  21.2  21.2
3  12.1  12.1  12.1
3  24.0  24.0  24.0
.....
```

Each point represent coordinates grouped in the same cell. Hence why the IDs repeat. Ideally I want to find the IDs (cells) that touch. I am calculating the euclidian distance as follow:

```
df_1 =pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', sep=',')

#calculate distances
coords = df_1[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].to_numpy()
distances = spsp.distance_matrix(coords, coords)
df_1['dist'] = distances.tolist()

# create new columns
dist_cols = ['d'+str(i) for i in (df_1['ID'])]
df_1[dist_cols] = df_1['dist'].apply(pd.Series)
df_1.to_csv('df_1.csv')
```

My problem is that I am getting a result that looks like this:
[image]

When ideally I should have many more columns because of how many rows I got (each ID is repeated 6 times). I think the problem is since the IDs are repeated the code is only calculating the distance of one ID instead of all the repetitions. I am struggling to be able to change this. 
Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

The following finds all pairwise distance between points and then matches them back up with the original dataframe's index and IDs.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"ID": 1, "X": 10.0, "Y": 10.0, "Z": 10.0},
        {"ID": 1, "X": 12.0, "Y": 12.0, "Z": 12.0},
        {"ID": 1, "X": 14.0, "Y": 14.0, "Z": 14.0},
        {"ID": 1, "X": 8.0, "Y": 8.0, "Z": 8.0},
        {"ID": 1, "X": 8.1, "Y": 8.1, "Z": 8.1},
        {"ID": 1, "X": 8.2, "Y": 8.2, "Z": 8.2},
        {"ID": 2, "X": 10.1, "Y": 10.1, "Z": 10.1},
        {"ID": 2, "X": 16.0, "Y": 16.0, "Z": 16.0},
        {"ID": 2, "X": 18.0, "Y": 18.0, "Z": 18.0},
        {"ID": 2, "X": 21.0, "Y": 21.0, "Z": 21.0},
        {"ID": 2, "X": 21.1, "Y": 21.1, "Z": 21.1},
        {"ID": 2, "X": 21.2, "Y": 21.2, "Z": 21.2},
        {"ID": 3, "X": 12.1, "Y": 12.1, "Z": 12.1},
        {"ID": 3, "X": 24.0, "Y": 24.0, "Z": 24.0},
    ]
)

upper_tri_indices = np.triu_indices(len(df), k=1)
id_combos = [df["ID"].iloc[idx].values for idx in upper_tri_indices]

dist_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "idx1": upper_tri_indices[0],
        "ID1": id_combos[0],
        "idx2": upper_tri_indices[1],
        "ID2": id_combos[1],
        "dist": pdist(df[["X", "Y", "Z"]]),
    }
)

print(dist_df)

    idx1  ID1  idx2  ID2       dist
0      0    1     1    1   3.464102
1      0    1     2    1   6.928203
2      0    1     3    1   3.464102
3      0    1     4    1   3.290897
4      0    1     5    1   3.117691
..   ...  ...   ...  ...        ...
86    10    2    12    3  15.588457
87    10    2    13    3   5.022947
88    11    2    12    3  15.761662
89    11    2    13    3   4.849742
90    12    3    13    3  20.611405

[91 rows x 5 columns]
```

You can then take this and reshape it how you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, Ideally I don't want to dramatically change my code, just help modifying the line 
```
dist_cols = ['d'+str(i) for i in (df_1['ID'])]
```
to make it permissive to have the same IDs repeated. If possible.